# can't get .on() method to work for slidetoggling children

Tags: jquery

I want the direct children of my ULs to slidetoggle when I click or hover my mouse over it. I'm not getting any errors, but it isn't doing anything when I click or hover over it. That way the DIV slides open and close displaying all the links in that category.

Script:

```
$("#LinksSet1, #LinksSet2").on('click mouseenter mouseleave', '> div', slideToggle());
```

HTML:

```
<ul id="LinksSet1">Microsoft
  <div>
    <li><a href="http://www.Microsoft.com">Microsoft Search</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Microsoft Images</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Microsoft Maps</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Microsoft Mail</a></li>
  </div>
</ul>
<ul id="LinksSet2">Microsoft
  <div>
    <li><a href="http://www.Microsoft.com">Microsoft Search</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Microsoft Images</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Microsoft Maps</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Microsoft Mail</a></li>
  </div>
</ul>
```

Comment: what kind of selector is `'> *'`?

Comment: Supposedly optional childselector for all direct children of element, but I haven't used it before.

Comment: Hmmmm, I've never seen that but I'm not an expert either. Good luck

Comment: While `> *` works isn't it easier and more readable to do `> div` in this case? Also your html is invalid since you have a div and text in `ul` https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ul

Comment: slideToggle is undefined

Comment: yes '> div' is a better idea. I don't know what you mean by invalid, but if you mean my text would toggle also, explicitly saying div is good.

Comment: @Palmer a `ul` can contain `zero or more <li> elements, eventually mixed with <ol> and <ul> elements.` see the link I provided. here you have text and div as a direction child of ul

Comment: the way my html is works perfectly fine with     $("#LinksSet2").hover(function(){
      $("#Links2").slideToggle();
but requires me to explicitly say each div and I can't specify to attach event to multiple elements to toggle their direct children.

Comment: Yes your html will render but it is invalid, google what that means if you don't know. slideToggle is called on a jquery object, and cannot be called alone, see http://jsfiddle.net/Q6mxB/ this is not complete code, just showing you how it works

Comment: I can't get     $("#LinksSet1").on('click mouseenter mouseleave', '> div', function(){ $(this).slideToggle(); });  to work at all. I'm not getting errors but like I was saying before nothing will toggle. Using IE8 and 1.11.1/jquery.min.js(sometimes I hate my job)

Comment: you want something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/PpL57/